# How to query a DynamoDB table to retreive only items which have a specific value inside an string-set attribute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

The items in my table have an attribute of type *string set*. I'll stick to the example from the documentation and call the set "colors". As the name indicates the set holds various strings representing colors in each item. This would look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kij0W.png).

Now I want to query the table so that I retrieve all items where a specific color is within the set. So in regards to the attached picture I would like to query for the color "Green" and want to receive the items Picture2 and Picture3.

Is there a way to do this?

Since the amount of all possible colors and items is huge plus the fact that only a very small amount of colors are associated to an item, a `scan` would be very inefficient. So far I tried to create a global secondary index (GSI) but it seems that its not possible in the way I want it or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the field you are searching for is built into the primary key or secondary index, `scan` will be your only option.

The `scan` operation will allow you to use the `contains` keyword to search the set

```
let params = {
    TableName : 'TABLE_NAME',
    FilterExpression: "contains(#color, :color)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#color": "color",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":color": "Blue",
    }       
};

documentClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

According to the [docs on secondary indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html), you cannot build an index using a set as the primary key

> The key schema for the index. Every attribute in the index key schema must be a top-level attribute of type String, Number, or Binary. Other data types, including documents and sets, are not allowed.

Comment: alright, thanks. I missed this paragraph from the documentation you mentioned.